# Download Typed Library from Windows Registry

Tags: c++, visual-studio, registry

I'm trying to develop a Node.js connection to a native C++ program that uses Asus's Aura SDK (Downloadable here https://www.asus.com/campaign/aura/uk/AURA-ready.php).

In the manual, says:

> The `#import` does the similar effect as `#include`, except that it gets the type information from the "Type Libraries" (reside in the Windows Registry) instead of header files. The GUID `F1AA5209-5217-4B82-BA7E-A68198999AFA` in the directive is the Lib ID of "AuraServiceLib", where the AURA SDK can be found.

I need this library for x86_64, but I don't know if it's available (I believe it is, as there are some examples in x64).

Is there any way to explore these libraries from the Windows Registry? How I could check if there is a x64 version of the library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless they are doing something very different from normal the actual type library is not stored in the registry, only a reference to where on the file system the tlb file is located.

To check where the SDK installed the TLB open regedit.exe and go to HKEY_CLASSES -> TypeLib -> {F1AA5209-5217-4B82-BA7E-A68198999AFA} ->   -> 0 and check for a "win64" key.  is likely to be "1.0", if there is such a win64 key the default value will be the path to the type library file.

Comment: Thanks! Yes... it seems there's only a 32 bit version: https://i.imgur.com/HcZL4C9.png